# execute WebView.loadurl() after Webview.clearView() multitimes will cause crash

Tags: android

execute WebView.loadurl() after Webview.clearView()  multitimes will cause crash. android 4.0.3. Here is the logcat output:

```
 Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/P700i/P700i:4.0.4/IMM76D/P700i_S105_120709:user/release-keys'                                
 pid: 4262, tid: 4284  >>> com.baidu.searchbox_lenovo <<<                                                                
 signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 006c0069                                                          
  r0 01f70298  r1 00000000  r2 01d31860  r3 006c0069                                                                     
  r4 01d31860  r5 015c6b48  r6 00000007  r7 4bfb1e0c                                                                     
  r8 5197fc08  r9 4bfb1e04  10 4bfb1dec  fp 5197fc1c                                                                     
  ip 508cdf1d  sp 5197fc00  lr 508cdf2b  pc 509ecf0c  cpsr 80003430                                                      
          #00  pc 003aff0c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so (_ZNK5Layer8getChildEi)                                            
          #01  pc 00290f26  /system/lib/libwebcore.so                                                                    
          #02  pc 0001ed70  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)                                                    
          #03  pc 00059924  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)                     
          #04  pc 00030bcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so                                                                        
          #05  pc 000344d4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z12dvmInterpretP6ThreadPK6MethodP6JValue)                            
          #06  pc 0006d710  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z14dvmCallMethodVP6ThreadPK6MethodP6ObjectbP6JValueSt9__va_list)     
          #07  pc 0006d734  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z13dvmCallMethodP6ThreadPK6MethodP6ObjectP6JValuez)                  
          #08  pc 00060612  /system/lib/libdvm.so                                                                        
          #09  pc 000132dc  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry)                                                         
 code around pc:                                                                                                         
 509eceec 47a868e1 f57a69a0 4620ec96 bf00bd7c  .h.G.iz... F|...                                                          
 509ecefc 0036b3ce 3088f8d0 bf3a4299 3080f8d0  ..6....0.B:....0                                                          
 509ecf0c 0021f853 47702000 e005b911 d0034288  S.!.. pG.....B..                                                          
 509ecf1c 280068c0 e000d1fa 47702001 41f0e92d  .h.(..... pG-..A                                                          
 509ecf2c f8c54605 460e10a0 f5d12400 4607fd43  .F.....F.$..C..F                                                          
 code around lr:                                                                                                         
 508cdf08 b9084603 e0042001 f8d34620 f6a311a4  .F... .. F......                                                          
 508cdf18 bd10fa0b 4614b510 2100b14b f11e4618  .......FK..!.F..                                                          
 508cdf28 4601ffeb 4620b118 ffe2f7ff 2001e000  ...F.. F.......                                                           
 508cdf38 bf00bd10 4ff0e92d 6d464607 460cb0a7  ....-..O.FFm...F                                                          
 508cdf48 0b90f10d 0a88f10d 52f4f8d6 f6f74628  ...........R(F..                                                          
 memory map around addr 006c0069:                                                                                        
 0000a000-0000b000 /system/bin/app_process                                                                               
 (no map for address)                                                                                                    
 0134c000-016eb000 [heap]                                                                                                
 stack:                                                                                                                  
     5197fbc0  5197fc1c                                                                                                  
     5197fbc4  4009baa8  /system/lib/libc.so                                                                             
     5197fbc8  4c0206a8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)                                                        
     5197fbcc  015c6b48  [heap]                                                                                          
     5197fbd0  00000003                                                                                                  
     5197fbd4  4bfb1f00                                                                                                  
     5197fbd8  5197fc08                                                                                                  
     5197fbdc  4009b9d8  /system/lib/libc.so                                                                             
     5197fbe0  5197fbe8                                                                                                  
     5197fbe4  4013bd6b  /system/lib/libutils.so                                                                         
     5197fbe8  000992e7                                                                                                  
     5197fbec  00000000                                                                                                  
     5197fbf0  41b62b80  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)                                                               
     5197fbf4  41b62b80  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)                                                               
     5197fbf8  df0027ad                                                                                                  
     5197fbfc  00000000                                                                                                  
 #01 5197fc00  4c1d2838  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)                                                        
     5197fc04  40a5dd74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Comment: It seems like I'm having the same problem.   did you solved it somehow?    are you absolutly sure its the clearView() method that causing it?   if yes - what is the crush statics (1 of 2 loading / 1 from 100 loadings)?  thanks

Comment: yes, definitely.  the only way is not to use clearView().

Comment: I removed from my code the clearView() method, and like a magic - I never sow that crash again since then.  thank you very for posting your question, It helped me a lot. I've been Struggling with this problem for a long time. seems like it really bug in the API.

Comment: I was doing the same, also suspected on clearview, removed it, but suddenly the problem started again... anybody in my situation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488032/webview-killing-the-whole-activity-how-can-i-debug-this